# Question concerning accumulation point

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose that we have to find an optimal solution $x^*$ to an optimization problem involving some function $f$, such that $0\in\partial f(x^*)$ where $\partial$ denotes the subdifferential.

Let $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence generated by some algorithm, satisfying $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} -x_{n}) = 0$, and that $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ has an accumulation point $\bar{x}$ (e.g. when the sequence is bounded).
Suppose further that this sequence has the following property:
$$x_{n+1} -x_{n} \in \partial f(x_n).$$
My question is: Under which conditions can we conclude that $0\in \partial f(\bar{x})$?

Thanks in advance for your discussions!

Comment: What is $\bar x$ in the last formula? And do you mean $0=f(\bar x)$?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth $\bar{x}$ is an accumulation point (a.k.a cluster point) of the sequence $x_n$ (if $x_n$ converges then there is a unique accumulation point that is the limit of $x_n$). The last line is a typo, should be $0\in\partial f(\bar{x})$. Thanks.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be convex? Are you actually assuming strong convergence of the sequence? In this case, the argument follows from weak-strong sequential closedness of the subdifferential.

Comment: @ChristianClason Yes $f$ is convex if that could make things easier. But  no strong convergence assumption is made, unfortunately. And I don't think that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} -x_{n}) = 0$ combined with the existence of an accumulation point of $x_n$ will lead to strong convergence.

Comment: If you only have weak (or no) convergence, then the conclusion doesn't hold.

Comment: @ChristianClason Thanks, but any arguments on that? For many optimization methods, the best they can do is to generate a (not necessarily convergent) sequence whose accumulation points are stationary points. For example: the conjugate gradient methods (see Theorem 4.3.1 in https://books.google.fr/books?id=o0BYHLhhPJMC&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=optimization+accumulation+point+stationary+point&source=bl&ots=Dxq8_d4g7N&sig=lA1pSDQsHRlpRqIzS5Dg154Ja24&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS_MPEipzQAhVBWxoKHdEOCzAQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=optimization%20accumulation%20point%20stationary%20point&f=false)

Comment: That is a different question. If the problem is finite-dimensional (hence weak convergence and strong convergence coincide) and you only want that accumulation points are stationary, then you can just look at the subsequence converging (strongly) to $\bar x$ and apply the closedness property of the subdifferential to obtain your conclusion. That's a relatively standard argument. (Look at Rockafellar's original paper proving convergence of the proximal point method.)

Comment: @ChristianClason Are you referring to this paper: http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr066-MonoOpProxPoint.pdf ? I must have made some mistake somewhere: Suppose further that $f$ is continuous. Denote by $S$ the set of indices of a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $\bar{x}$. Let $(y_m)_{m\ge 0}$ be this subsequence, i.e. $(y_m)_{m\ge 0} = (x_n)_{n\in S}$. Let $(z_m)_{m\ge 0} = (x_{n+1})_{n\in S}$....

Comment: @ChristianClason (next) From $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} -x_{n}) = 0$ we have $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} (z_{m} -y_{m}) = 0$. From $x_{n+1} -x_{n} \in \partial f(x_n)$ we have $z_{m} - y_{m} \in \partial f(y_m)$, or equivalently $f(x) - f(y_m) \ge (z_m-y_m)^T(x-y_m) \ \forall x$. Taking the limit $m\to +\infty$ we get $f(x) - f(\bar{x}) \ge 0 \ \forall x$, i.e. $0\in\partial f(\bar{x})$.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. It suffices that $f$ is lower semi-continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds if

- $f$ is **convex, proper and lower semi-continuous** (in which case the subdifferential is weakly-strongly closed) and
- $x_n\to \bar x$ **strongly** (in particular, if $\{x_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^N$).

(If $\bar x$ is just an accumulation point, you can apply this argument to the subsequence converging to it.)

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I thought this was solved in my previous comment? It would be very useful if you could write down a *rigorous* proof with a focus on why the above conditions are **necessary**, especially the convexity and strong convergence (note that these two are not given in my question).

Comment: It was, I just wanted to put down something so it wouldn't stay unanswered. I'm not claiming that these conditions are necessary, merely sufficient. These conditions were given in your comments, though. Without strong convergence, I don't think you can get the conclusion, because the subdifferential is not weakly-weakly closed (you can't take the limit $m\to\infty$ in your comment because the product of weakly convergent sequences does not converge in general).

Comment: In my (last) comment to the question, I did not make use of the convexity and the strong convergence. I think they are not necessary (but I may be mistaken). In my comment the sequences with the index $n$ are not convergent, while those with the index $m$ (i.e. subsequences extracted from $(.)_n$ are strongly convergent.

Comment: You did make use of strong convergence, because you were taking the limit in $(z_m-y_m)^T(x-y_m)$. This only works if $y_m$ converges strongly. (You did indeed not use convexity; this is only required to ensure that the subdifferentials are not empty, but if you know this by other means, this assumption is not necessary.)

Comment: Even if $(x_n)$ does not converge strongly to $\bar{x}$, one can always extract a subsequence $(x_m)$ that converges strongly to $\bar{x}$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct (take any orthonormal basis such as $u_n = \sin(nx)$, which converges weakly to zero but is constant in norm).

Answer (score 0):

The condition 
$$x_{n+1} -x_{n} \in \partial f(x_n)$$
does not make any sense because the units do not match. Think of $x$ having units seconds and $f$ having units meters. Then the left hand side has units seconds and the right meters per second.

Reasonable algorithms do not tolerate such mismatches because they are not invariant under rescaling (e.g., using km instead of m as units).

Comment: Sorry I don't really get that. How about $f(x)=1/2\|x\|^2$? $x$ and $\partial f(x)$ have the same unit, right? The true algorithm that I encountered is more complicated than that, I just wanted to write a similar but simpler example for the question. Another similar example is ADMM: http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf, at the end of page 18 they have: $\rho A^TB(z^{k+1} - z^k) \in \partial f(x^{k+1}) + A^Ty^{k+1}$.

Comment: @Wolfgang: The same argument goes for steepest descent, and that hasn't stopped people from (successfully) doing it :) (Although thinks work better if you remember that subgradients -- just like derivatives -- are properly elements of the *dual* space and hence some sort of Riesz representative or duality mapping is required to make this work in function spaces.)

Comment: @Khue -- the matrices $A,B$ are meant to scale things. They have physical units that ensure that the left and right hand sides have matching units. You need to come up with something similar in your algorithm.

Comment: @ChristianClason -- precisely! You make my point :-) (You could also argue that steepest descent only works with a step size factor, and that this step size factor is a dimension-less number times a scaling constant.)

Comment: That is true. You'd probably also enjoy Roland Herzog's talks where he motivates the proper preconditioners for saddle point problems by dimensional analysis :)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: I was also thinking about what you meant when writing $\rho A^TB...$. But what if in my problem I have $A=B=I$? Just to argue for the validity of the question. You have a point here, though ;) Any good references to learn more on the subject please?

Comment: Also thanks to @ChristianClason for the keywords :D

Comment: Mmh, how does this relate to the proximal point algorithm? It actually does not need a scaling…

Comment: @Dirk That is because the prox-mapping includes the scaling via the duality mapping ($\mathrm{prox}_f = (J_X + \partial f)^{-1}$), and only if  $X$ is a Hilbert space that you identify with its dual do you get the usually (at least in the context of optimization) seen $J_X= I$.

Comment: @Khue In the finite-dimensional setting, people usually do not distinguish between the *derivative* (which is a linear mapping; in your first example, $f'(x)$ maps $h$ to $x^T h$) and the *gradient* (which is the Riesz representative of the derivative according to some inner product; in your example, and choosing the standard inner product, $\nabla f(x) = x$). Implicitly, this always assumes the standard Euclidean inner product, but depending on where the finite-dimensional problem came from, this might be the wrong choice, and lead to the scaling errors Wolfgang mentioned.